# How to create a group if more than 2 checkboxes are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

In my app designed for sending SMS, I have a form which will accept username,email and mobile number.So after entering the all the fields when user press the add button then all the informations are displayed on then having a check-box.

Now I wanted if more than 1 check box are selected then it should ask whether you want to create a group or send SMS. If yes then it will create a group.This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/93/) which shows form.

Please tell me how to check if *multiple* check-boxes are selected.

### JavaScript

```
var val=0;
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#btn1').click(function() {

   if( $(".span4").val() != "" ) {
       $("#mytable").append('<tr id="mytr'+val+'"></tr>');
       $("#mytr"+val).append("<td class=\"cb\">" +
                                  "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"yes\" ></td>");

       $(".span4").each(function() {
           $("#mytr"+val).append("<td >"+$(this).val()+"</tr>");
       });
       val++;

    } else {
         alert("please fill the form completely");
    }

  });
});
```

### Screenshot

[image: fiddle screenshot]

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: `$("#mytr"+val).append("<td >"+$(this).val()+"</tr>");` what is this???

Comment: A little easier if you provide the checkbox with a class: `$('.checkboxClass:checked').length == 0` then no checkboxes are checked.

Comment: @MackieeE I am allowing user to select multiple checkboxes

Comment: @ManjunathHegde this will show the newley entered records,Please run the jsfiddle,enter all the inputs and press add button.You will know why those lines are meant for

Answer (score 0):

```
var countChecked = function() {
  return $( "input:checked" ).length;
}
```

create group:

```
$( "input:checked" ).each(function(i,v) {
 $(v).attr('name','chk_group[]');
}
```

EDIT: ..
.........

```
 $("#mytr"+val).append("<td >"+$(this).val()+"</tr>");

              });

             $("#mytr"+val).find('input').change(function() {
                if ($('input:checked').length > 1)
                {
                    $('input:checked').attr('name','group_name[]');
                } else
                {
                  $('input').attr('name','');
                }
            });
          val++;
```

............

Comment: but how to create group if multiple checkboxes are selected

Comment: how can you create a group in the fiddle?you fiddle and http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/93/ Are same

Comment: @MackieeE yes true i didnt understand.the fiddle i have given and the baltow fiddle are having same functionality

Comment: @javaBeginner what do you mean under "group" ?
This code create group from checkboxes, that you can send to server
[link](http://www.wastedpotential.com/html-multi-checkbox-set-the-correct-way-to-group-checkboxes/)

Comment: @baltov see suppose you have 10 records ,you want to create a group of 1st row,5th row and 9th row.My app is regarding sending sms.Its just like phone book contacts.Suppose in phone you want to send sms to family groups then just type a message and select group family.Suppose if you want to send sms to friends group then type a message and select friends group

Comment: @javaBeginner, sorry, you describe requirements, not what you want, What is "create group"? Do you want to create html elements? Do you want to send request to server? or only alert to ask "Create group or send sms" ? If you want alert, replace all after  if ($('input:checked').length > 1) with alert. Or create pop-up.Please be more accurate! You ask: "Please tell me how to check if multiple check-boxes are selected.". We show you how!

Comment: @baltov In the fiddle that i have provided it creates rows but its not sending datas to server.similarily I want when you create 2 or more check boxes,it will create a group(but will not send datas to server)

Answer (score 0):

`$("#mytr"+val).append("<td class=\"cb\"><input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"yes\" checked ></td>");`

try this

and I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/104/)

Comment: it will check the check box while appending the row to the table

Comment: Thanks for answering but i do not want this.When you press the checkbox then it will show option to create group or not like an confirm alert.Your code simply by default checkbox is selected

Comment: see you entered all the input fields name,email and mobile.Then press add button.Now you will see one record in at similarly add 3 records.Now you will have 3 records.Suppose you want to create a group of 2 numbers so you select 2 checkboxes.Now i want how to create a group

Comment: you should put another button for that right? otherwise on on every check it will ask you to create a group, isn't that dirty??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40103/discussion-between-javabeginner-and-manjunath-hegde)

Comment: yes a button ,hidden div and the hidden div should be enabled if i select more than one checkbox

Comment: Can i have the fiddle?

Comment: are you there in stackoverflow chat?

Answer (score 0):

give a class to the checkbox
on clicking of any checkbox that has the same class call a function

eg:

```
$(".chekboxclass").on('blur',function(){
       var checkedCount = 0;       
       $(".chekboxclass").each(function(){
         if($(this).is(':checked')){

            checkedCount++;
         }

       })    
       if(checkedCount >1){
          alert('do u want to create a group');
       }
    })
```

This is a sample code. I have not tested it yet.

Hope this is what u are looking for